# Why are headings and paragraphs considered as clickable elements (HTML)

Tags: html, accessibility, plotly-dash

I am trying to make my webapp (created with Python Dash) more accessible, e.g. for users relying on screen readers. In order to test my webapp I use the Accessibility Inspector built into Firefox. Here I run into issues concerning focusability and interactivity of elements which are supposed to show text (e.g. headings and paragraphs).

First I created my elements like this:

```
    html.H1(
     children="this is my header"
    )
    
    html.P(
     children="this is text"
    )`
```

In these cases the Accessibility Inspector yields the following warning:

**Clickable elements must be focusable and should have interactive semantics**

In order to resolve this, I added 'tabIndex' to my elements:

```
    html.H1(
     children="this is my header",
     tabIndex='0'
    )
    
    html.P(
     children="this is text",
     tabIndex='0'
    )
```

This eliminated one part of the warning. Now I got this warning:
**Focusable elements should have interactive semantics**

From what I gathered on accessibility so far it is bad practice to give non interactive elements like headings a 'tabIndex'. So my second approach is probably already going in the wrong direction.

Can you please tell me how to deal with the first warning instead? And why are headings and paragraphs considered as clickable elements? They do not contain a link or anything else.

**Update**:
If I take a look at the HTML in Firefox, the header looks like this:
[screenshot HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F13mt.png)

**Solution**: I asked my question in the Plotly Community Forum (https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-remove-events-from-dash-html-components-to-avoid-misinterpretation-by-screen-readers/70477) as well. They pointed me towards the dash mantine components library (https://www.dash-mantine-components.com/), which includes dmc.Title and dmc.Text which can be used instead of html.H1-H6 and html.P. This resolves my issue.

Comment: What does the output HTML look like? (Before adding the tab index, that shouldn't be required)

Comment: @DBS I added a screenshot to the original post. Do you mean that by output HTML?

Comment: This warning is due to `click` or other events bound to these elements. Is there any debugging console that might do that? In your screen shot it’s bound to react, so it might only occur in the development environment…

Comment: If it’s not your code that binds to these elements, and no user interaction is expected, you can safely ignore that warning. You should *not add tabindex* to make it go away. Doing so will add a problem that didn’t exist before (:

Answer (score 0):

I looked at some sample Dash applications, https://dash.gallery/dash-clinical-analytics/, and indeed the headings on that demo are "clickable".

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

"Clinical Analytics" is an `<h5>` and "Welcome to the Clinical Analytics Dashboard" is an `<h3>`.  Both have an event handler for the click event.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

That will cause some screen readers to say those elements are "clickable".  Here's what NVDA says when I use the <kbd>H</kbd> key to navigate to the headings:

- *"Clinical Analytics, heading, **clickable**, level 5"*
- *"Welcome to the Clinical Analytics Dashboard, heading, **clickable**, level 3"*

The screen reader is trying to help the user let them know that an event handler is on that element and that it can be clicked on.  However, headings are not normally considered interactive elements so it'll be confusing.

This seems like a bug in Dash.

The error you're getting, "Clickable elements must be focusable and should have interactive semantics" is accurate.  It has two parts:

1. "**elements must be focusable**" - anything that you can interact with using a mouse should be interactable (word?) with the keyboard.  In order to interact with the element, you first have to be able to get your keyboard focus to it, thus the error message.
2. "**elements should have interactive semantics**" - when a screen reader user navigates to an interactive element, they should hear the [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) of that element and that role should convey that the element is an interactive element.  The headings **do** have semantics, NVDA says they're "*headings*", as noted above, but the error message says it should be "interactive semantics", not just "semantics".

All this info doesn't explain how to *fix* your problem but I wanted to post the "why" of the error message, and I couldn't fit all this into a simple comment :-)